# c++ programming define array size from the external input file?

Tags: c++

I want to define array size from the external input.

I create the code like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void loadIt(int[],int);//loadIT prototype

int main()
{   
    ofstream outfile("C:\\sir.txt");
    if (!outfile){
    cerr << "Output file could not be opened" << endl;
    exit(1);}

    outfile << setiosflags(ios::fixed|ios::showpoint);
    outfile << setprecision(3);
    outfile << setiosflags(ios::fixed|ios::showpoint);
    outfile << setprecision(3);

    const int arraySize = 20; //here i want the input from the external file
    int a[arraySize];


     loadIt(a, arraySize);//call to loadIT

}
```

i want to define array size from the external file..plz help me

Comment: You can't modify an array size if you're not stitching the data in your source file and then re-compiling it dynamically. You can use malloc to allocate as much data you want though.

Comment: @DavidKernin I think what he means is read `arraySize` from a file (or calculate it from its size).

Comment: You can use `stat` to find out the size of the file and then, use `int * a = new[sz];` to allocate the memory.

Comment: or even use `std::vector<std::uint8_t> a(sz);`.

Comment: @m0skit0 I think you're right..

Comment: @unxnut can you give the example for this

Comment: I think unxnut explained it pretty good, give it a try; don't expect us to do your work for you.

Comment: but what to do i can not clear @m0skit0

Comment: @user2932548 1. use `stat` to find out the size of the file 2. `int * a = new[sz];`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want, but following may help:

```
std::ifstream in("C:\\input.txt");

int size;
in >> size;
std::vector<int> a(size);
```

Assuming input.txt is something like

```
42
// Possible other values.
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in array type has a fixed size, so you can only use a compile-time constant to specify the size. You'll need a dynamic array, which is provided by `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>

const int arraySize = read_array_size_from_wherever();
std::vector<int> a(arraySize);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    const char * fn = "stat.c";
    struct stat buf;
    stat ( fn, &buf );
    std::cout << "File size: " << buf.st_size << std::endl;

    int * a = new int[buf.st_size];

    // Do your processing

    delete[] a;

    return ( 0 );
}
```